# Dart - swap list item or pop item from list

Tags: list, dart

Using Dart, what is a good way of iterating through a list of strings in search for a specific one, when string is found move it to the front of the list?

For example, if looking for the letter 'b'. Find it, move it up front.

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
 => ['b',  'a', 'c']
```

Not knowing Dart very well, I solved it with simple for-loop

```
List<String> example = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (int i = 0; i< example.length; i++) {
  if (example[i] == 'b') {
      final temp = example[0];
      example[0] = example[i];
      example[i] = temp;
  }
}
```

Is there a way in dart to call some array method on a list to find a specific item, remove it from the original list and return the removed item? Like `.splice()` in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for List delete and then insert to move it up to front

```
if(example.remove("b"))
      example.insert(0, "b");
```

Answer (score 3):

### Properties of the List data structure

When approaching this problem it is helpful to know some properties of the list data structure:

- Changing the value at an index is fast.
- Adding or removing items from the end of a list is fast.
- Removing items from the beginning or middle of a list is slow because all the items after it need to move up one index.
- Adding an item to the beginning or middle of a list is slow because all the items after it need to move back one index.

### Removing and inserting

Thus, although @FloW's answer is very concise and easy to read, it's slow because it requires both removing from the middle of a list and adding to the beginning of a list:

```dart
final example = ["a", "b", "c"];
if (example.remove("b")) {
  example.insert(0, "b");
}
```

For short lists it probably doesn't matter but for long lists this could have noticeable performance impacts.

### Swapping

Since the requirements in the original problem allow for swapping rather than removing and inserting, the for loop solution given in the question itself is better in my opinion:

```dart
List<String> example = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (int i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  if (example[i] == 'b') {
    final temp = example[0];
    example[0] = example[i];
    example[i] = temp;
  }
}
```

Although this search still requires visiting every item in the list, it doesn't require moving everything if a match is found. Only the two affected indices are changed.

You could improve the efficiency even more by adding a `break` statement to the end of the `if` block, which would make it equivalent to using `indexOf`:

```dart
final example = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
final value = 'b';
final index = example.indexOf(value);
example[index] = example[0];
example[0] = value;
```